# Splitting Text File - Column to Rows in Python

Tags: python

I have a txt file which looks like:

```
X Y Z I
1 1 1 10
2 2 2 20
3 3 3 30
4 4 4 40
5 5 5 50
6 6 6 60
7 7 7 70
8 8 8 80
9 9 9 90
```

I want to split 4th column to 3 rows and export it to txt file.

```
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90
```

This is just example. In my goal I have to split column with 675311 values into 16471 rows with 41 values. So first 41 values in column "I" will be first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), this is trivial and potentially more flexible:

**Edit:** added parameters for selecting which column to pick and how many columns the output table will have. You can change it to fit whatever shape you want the output to be.

```
import numpy as np

datacolumn = 3
outputcolumns = 3
data = np.genfromtxt('path/to/csvfile',skip_header=True)
column = data[:,datacolumn]
reshaped = column.reshape((len(column)/outputcolumns,outputcolumns))
np.savetxt('path/to/newfile',reshaped)
```

**Edit:** separated out comments from code for readability. Here's what each line does:

```
# Parse CSV file with header
# Extract 4th column
# Reshape column into new matrix
# Save matrix to text file
```

Comment: "reshaped = column.reshape((len(column)/3,3))"
If I want split column with 675311 values into 16471x41 matrix I have to put this values as parameters to reshape?

Comment: have you tried it on a file that does not have a multiple of 3 rows?

Comment: generalized the example with parameters to control which data column to pick and what the shape of the output will be

Answer (score 0):

```
with open ( 'in.txt' , 'r') as f:
    f.next() '# skip header
    l = [x.split()[-1] for x in f]
    print [l[x:x+3] for x in xrange(0, len(l),3)]
[['10', '20', '30'], ['40', '50', '60'], ['70', '80', '90']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I made a list of all the numbers you wanted to write to the text file, then in another for loop with an output text file open, I looped through that list (using indicies because on every third one you wanted a new line). Then I have a local variable that is one more than i called j. I use that to check if i + 1 is a multiple of 3 (since I start at 0 every third iteration + 1 will be a multiple of 3). I write a new line character and continue on my way. If it is not a multiple of 3, I write a space and continue on my way.

```
nums = []
with open ('input.txt' , 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line.split(' ')
        num = s[3]
        nums.append(num)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        num = nums[i].strip('\n')
        f.write(num)
        j = i + 1
        if j%3 == 0:
            f.write('\n')
        else:
            f.write(' ')
```